# Docker with Ruby on Rails on a development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I'm learning Docker and I'm trying to configure a Ruby on Rails project to run on it (on development environment). But I'm having some trouble.

I managed to configure docker-compose to start a container with the terminal open, so I can do bundle install, start a server or use rails generators. However, every time I run the command to start, it starts a new container, where I have to do bundle install again (it takes a while).

So I'd like to know if there is a way to reuse components already created.

Here is my Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM ruby:2.7.4-bullseye

WORKDIR '/apps/gaia_api'

EXPOSE 3000

RUN gem install rails bundler

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

And here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  gaia_api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: "."
    volumes:
      - .:/apps/gaia_api
    environment:
      - USER_DB_RAILS
      - PASSWORD_DB_RAILS
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

The command I'm using to run is: `docker-compose run --service-ports gaia_api`.

I tried to use the docker commands `build`, `create` and `start`, however the volume mapping doesn't work. On the terminal of the container, the files of the volume are not there.

The commands I tried.

```
docker build -t gaia -f Dockerfile.dev .
docker create -v ${pwd}:/apps/gaia_api -it -p 3000:3000 gaia
docker start -i f36d4d9044b08e42b2b9ec1b02b03b86b3ae7da243f5268db2180f3194823e48
```

There is probably something I still don't understand. So I ask: Whats the best way to configure docker for ruby on rails development? And will it be possible to add new services later (I plan once I get the first part to work, to add postgres and a vue project).

**EDIT:** Forgot to say that I'm on Mac OS Big Sur

**EDIT 2:** I found what was wrong with the volumes, I was tying `-v ${pwd}:/apps` instead of `$(pwd):/apps`.

Comment: if you are using docker-compose, then you can directly try docker-compose build, docker-compose up to start the container.

Comment: @RohitLingayat If i do that, the container imediatly ends.

Comment: can you send me the error log?